# Rust Borrow Semantics String

Tags: rust

I have a block of code

```
let mut current_room = None;

for (ref room_id, ref poker_room) in &self.planning_pokers {
    if poker_room.has_player(user_id.clone()) {
        current_room = Some(room_id.clone());
        break
    }
}

match current_room {
    Some(room_id) => {
        self.planning_pokers.get_mut(&room_id.clone()).unwrap().remove_player(user_id.clone());
        if self.planning_pokers.is_empty() {
            self.planning_pokers.remove(&room_id.clone());
        }
    },
    None => (),
    _ => ()
}

println!("Player {} joined room {}", join_room.room_id.clone(), user_id.clone());
if self.planning_pokers.contains_key(&join_room.room_id.clone()) {

}
```

This fails to compile due to a mutable and immutable borrow conflict. The conflict in question pertains to me setting the value of `current_room` to `Some(room_id.clone())`. If I instead do `Some(room_id.clone().to_string())` everything works as expected. Why is this the case? And why does the rust compiler give me an error that is seemingly unrelated?

For reference this is the error:

> cannot borrow `self.planning_pokers` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `room_id` is a double reference of type `&&T`. This means that in `Some(room_id.clone())`, you are *cloning a borrowed reference to data* that `self.planning_pokers` owns, rather than cloning the underlying data itself. Because you then assign it to the variable `current_room` in the outer scope, `self.planning_pokers` remains borrowed throughout.  It might help to see that in this case, `current_room` is of type `Option<&T>`.

`Some(room_id.to_string())` instead creates a copy of the underlying data which is moved into `current_room`. In this case `current_room` is of type `Option<T>`.

The difference is (I believe) due to Rust's [auto-dereferencing behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28552082/394331). Immutable references implement `Clone`, and so Rust calls the method on `&T`. However, they do not implement `ToString`, so Rust dereferences all the way down to `T`.

---

Note: [rust-clippy](https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/rust-clippy) warns about this very issue. From the [wiki](https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/rust-clippy/wiki#clone_double_ref):

### clone_double_ref

**What it does:** Checks for usage of .clone() on an &&T.

**Why is this bad?** Cloning an &&T copies the inner &T, instead of cloning the underlying T.

**Example:**

```
fn main() {
   let x = vec![1];
   let y = &&x;
   let z = y.clone();
   println!("{:p} {:p}",*y, z); // prints out the same pointer
}
```